# Intellij IDEA auto completion order

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Typing `str` give me `strictfp` as first offer and `String`  as second. Is there any way to change auto completion offers order and set `String` as first one?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make `String` as a 1st choice in this use case since the letter case matches better for `strictftp` which is also relevant for this place. Related https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221540

Comment: how does it help to have `String` as first offer? i need to customize the order of list

Comment: Right, sorry. I've changed the answer.